# Rails: Override and also use existing gem module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a gem with a helper module. 
eg

Gem module

```
module Hotel
 module MenuItem
  def menu(session)
    x = DEFAULT_FOOD_MENU[session]
  end

  def print_menu(menu)
    #printing menu
  end
end
```

custom class

```
module SizzSuzzHotel
 module MenuItem
   include Hotel::MenuItem
  def menu(session)
    # I want to use the default menu item and also specific menu related to this hotel! . 
  end
end

module SizzSuzzHotel
 class order
  include MenuItem
    def order(session)
       menu_item = menu(session)  
       print(menu_item)
    end


  end
end
```

Here I want to override the menu and I want to use the existing print_menu!
How can I achieve this? use the gem module method and also add few more stuffs into it?

Answer (score 2):

If you include the `MenuItem` module, both methods will be available, so you can easily redefine one of them.

```
include MenuItem

def menu(session)
  ... here you write you custom menu method behaviour
end

def order(session)
  menu_item = menu(session) # => above menu method will be called
  print(menu_item) # => print method from MenuItem module will be called
end
```

Comment: I don't want to copy/paste or rewrite the base **menu(session)** function. Like using a super in class method , is there a better approach to reuse the gem method here?